# JsonSchema - binding redirect issue of Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json.net

In a project I use both libraries:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="NJsonSchema" Version="10.5.2" />
```

And in the following code, it fails when trying to build the schema:

```
var schema = JsonSchema.FromType<T>(new JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings
{
    AlwaysAllowAdditionalObjectProperties = true,
    FlattenInheritanceHierarchy = true,
    GenerateEnumMappingDescription = true,
    SerializerSettings = JsonFormatter.JsonSerializerSettings
});
```

Error:

> error CS1705: Assembly 'SubscriptionManager.Functions' with identity
> 'SubscriptionManager.Functions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
> uses 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
> which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' with identity 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'

I do not have a web.config or app.config file, because it's a library project.
In Dependencies --> Packages --> Newtonsoft.Json is pointed correctly with the right version.

Do you know what could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: `NJsonSchema` [depends](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NJsonSchema/#) on the `Newtonsoft.Json`. So, you don't have to refer the Newtonsoft directly.

Comment: Hi @PeterCsala, thank you for your reply! I have removed the referring to Newtonsoft directly and I still get the same error. I can't understand from where that version 12.0.0 comes, because I am not using it in this project. I have other dotnet projects on my computer that use Newtonsoft 12.0.0. But why does it read libs from other projects? I am also using Refit library.

Comment: Let suppose that `ProjectB` refers to `NugetPackageC`. Let's have a reference for `ProjectB` from `ProjectA`. From now on `ProjectA` can also access `NugetPackageC`.

Comment: I have double checked and I don't have such references. In my case, ProjectB is not referenced in ProjectA.

Comment: Hello, I have found out that this error is also thrown in debug mode when using an older version of Refit (4.7), that does not need importing the nuget NewtsonsoftJson independently. And it works fine, even if the exception is there in debug mode. I think there is an inconsistency in  Refit.Newtonsoft.Json version 13.0.0.0 combined with Refit version 6.0 (that I was trying to use.)